# (How) can I make `git log --first-parent` default?

Tags: git, git-config

Can I make `git log --first-parent` the default behaviour, such that when I type

```
git log
```

it actually does:

```
git log --first-parent
```

After configuring this, how would I call `git log` then using the previous behaviour?

```
# something like this:
git log --all-parents
```

Can I actually do this or do I need to create an alias different from `git log` like `git lg`:

```
git config --global alias.lg "log --first-parent"
```

Comment: If I remember well you cannot override a git command, unless you intercept the git executable itself (it is probably not your case). An alias is the easier way here.

Comment: You will need the alias, yes. (Or, as @MarcoLuzzara mentioned, you can write a `git` program that checks what Git program you're trying to run, and tweaks the arguments first if appropriate. But [this way lies madness](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/264500.html).